# combine two matrices based on row names

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have several matrices, each having different row numbers and names, but same column names. I want to combine these matrices. For example I have matrix m1 as

```
m1 = round(matrix(c(rnorm(18,5,1)), nrow = 6, ncol = 3), digits = 0)

rownames(m1)<- c(LETTERS[1:5], "J")
colnames(m1) <- c(letters[1:3])
> m1
  a b c
A 3 7 6
B 4 5 5
C 6 6 6
D 5 4 5
E 4 7 6
J 5 5 4
```

and second matrix:

```
m2 = round(matrix(c(rnorm(6, mean = 2)), nrow = 3, ncol = 2), digits = 0)
rownames(m2)<-c("A", "c", "J")
colnames(m2) <- c(letters[1:2])
m2
  a b
A 1 0
c 3 2
J 1 3
```

and I want output like this:

```
  a b c a b
A 3 7 6 1 0
B 4 5 5
C 6 6 6 3 2
D 5 4 5
E 4 7 6
J 5 5 4 1 3
```

How to do it in R?

Comment: `merge(m1, m2, by = "row.names", all = TRUE)`

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Or is the second row name in `m2` supposed to be a capital `C`?

Comment: It is supposed to be capital C, typing error. My bad!